# Visualforce HTTP POST limits

Tags: visualforce

I have an external application which needs to send temperature data every second via POST requests to Salesforce. From what I have seen, the REST api has a limit of 1000 calls per 24 hours per license. Can this limit be surpassed by using a Visualforce page and sending POST data to it instead ? - or are there any other ways ?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I believe the 24-hour limit is 15,000 + (1000 * total number of sfdc licenses) (based on [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm)). That's better, but still not enough to support 1 request each second.

Comment: Also, why do you think you need to update Salesforce every second? Why not simply gather/buffer your data (from outside of Salesforce), that comes in each second, for a minute or two and then send that to Salesforce?

Comment: "Every" second should not be correct approach, what if request delayed by 1 sec at Salesforce end. Instead make chunks and send the data every 2 min (safe).

Comment: Every second is way to chatty to be reasonable. What edition are you using?

Comment: It does not need to be exactly every second, as there also is timestamp data coming in. However, I would also like to know if there are any other ways to get this into Salesforce. Customer would like to have realtime updates, so batch is not possible here. Or perhaps Salesforce might not even be the solution here. Enterprise edition.

Comment: Your client says that they want 'real-time', but I doubt they _need_ (or would truly use) real-time. Surely they aren't going to have someone checking the data feed continuously. I'd set up a meeting with your client to try to work out what information they're trying to extract from the raw temperature/time data, and why they think they need real-time data. My guess would be that their true goal is to monitor for crossing a temperature threshold (and maybe only if it stays over/under the threshold for a set time) to send an alert of some flavor.

Answer (score 0):

**API LIMIT** *is not 1000*:-

[image]

Refer to following link for the above text/table: [API Requests Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm)

This applies to POST request to Visualforce page also. Calling the component without login to UI is count against API LIMIT.

"Every" second should not be correct approach, what if request delayed by 1 sec at Salesforce end. Instead make chunks and send the data every 2 min (safe).

Comment: Probably best to include a text reference to what the actual value is. Also it actually does list 1000 calls for the `Salesforce` license type for some editions.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I wanted to show all details in a table for better visibility so, thats the best (and quick) way I could find. Limit is 1000 per license in addition to 15000 upto 1 million. Here the user is confused, I guess.

Comment: Ah, right I missed the 15k baseline aspect as well. I agree the table is useful, but you should have it in writing somewhere what the actual limit is. It would make your answer a lot more useful and accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with having records created every second isn't going to be API limits, if you have a decent number of API calls. For example, in my org, we could literally send an API request every 7 milliseconds and not quite cap our API limit per day. Instead, the main problem is going to be storage space. Even though we can send over 160 API calls per second, we only have enough storage space to store 12 days worth of 7 millisecond-spaced data. We'd have to be deleting old data every week or so just to avoid filling up all of our space. You might want to talk to your client about the storage requirements of using one record per second. It's overkill in most cases. You might still decide to feed the data once per second, but you'll need a way to aggregate all that data so you don't overwhelm your client's storage space.